# Stored procedure execution in sql server agent job

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, scheduler, jobs

I would like to execute a stored procedure which populates data to table using nightly job.

```
sp_WarehouseAttendance_New:

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_WarehouseAttendance_New]
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

---------delete existing warehouse table------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New; 
--------Create New Table--------------------------------------------------
---Weeks------------------------------------------------------------------
With weeks as 
(select VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year, min(VDC_day_date) as WeekCommence
from sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender
where VDC_avail = 'T'
group by VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year),

---TTWeeks----------------------------------------------------------------
TTWeeks as

(SELECT VDC_Cal_Year as REMSYear, [VDC_week_no] as WholeYearWeekNo, WeekCommence,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vdc_cal_year ORDER BY VDC_week_no) as TermTimeWeekNo FROM weeks)

---Main----------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT    CASE WHEN STYR_Age_end_Aug < 16 THEN '1416' WHEN STYR_Age_end_Aug < 19 THEN '1618' ELSE '19+' END AgeBand,
REGT_Year, RTRIM(PRPH_ML1) AS PRPH_ML1, 
RTRIM(PRPH_ML2) AS PRPH_ML2, 
ML2.GNCD_Description AS [Curriculum Area], 
RTrim(PRPH_ML2) AS Section, 
q.GNCD_Description AS Section_Name, LEFT(q.GNCD_Description, 3) AS Dept, 
rtrim(REGT_Provision_Code) as REGT_Provision_Code, rtrim(PRPH_Title) as PRPH_Title, 
REGT_Student_ID, STEN_Student_ID, STEN_Funding_Stream, STYR_Age_end_Aug, REGS_Session_No, 
rtrim(REGH_Class_Register) as REGH_Class_Register, RTRIM(REGH_Register_Title) as REGH_Register_Title, REGH_Day, 
CASE WHEN REGH_Day = '1' THEN 'Sunday' WHEN REGH_Day = '2' THEN 'Monday' 
WHEN REGH_Day = '3' THEN 'Tuesday' WHEN REGH_Day = '4' THEN 'Wednesday'
WHEN REGH_Day = '5' THEN 'Thursday' WHEN REGH_Day = '6' THEN 'Friday' 
WHEN REGH_Day = '7' THEN 'Saturday' END AS Register_Day, [REGH_Start_Time] ,[REGH_End_Time],
CASE WHEN (REGTrgstudt.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '27%' OR
REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'MA27%' OR REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'FS%') 
THEN 'FunctionalSkill' 
WHEN REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '16%' THEN 'GCSE' WHEN REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/F%' OR REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/D%' OR
REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/E%' OR
REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/X%' THEN 'Main' ELSE 'Addition' END AS CourseType, 
CASE WHEN isnull(RGAT_Present,'X') IN ('N', 'Y','X') and REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE()
THEN REGS_Duration - isnull(REGD_Mins_Late,0) ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Poss, 
CASE WHEN isnull(RGAT_Present,'X') = 'Y' and REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN 
REGS_Duration - REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Att, 
CASE WHEN RGAT_Present = 'Y' and REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Late, 
[REGS_Session_Date] as Session_Date,
TermTimeWeekNo, REGH_ISN, PRPH_ISN, STUD_Surname, 
STUD_Forename_1, REGD_Attendance_Mark,
REGT_start_date, REGT_End_date, WeekCommence,
STFM_LearnFAMCode,
CASE 
WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=1 THEN '14-15 year old learner is eligible for free meals'
WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=2 THEN '16-19 year old learner is eligible for and in receipt of free meals'
ELSE 'N/A'
END AS FreeMealsIndicator,
CASE 
STFM_LearnFAMCode=36 THEN 'Care to Learn (C2L) (EFA funded only)'
STFM_LearnFAMCode=55 THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner member of a vulnerable group (EFA funded only)' 
WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=56 THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner awarded discretionary bursary (EFA funded only)'   
WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=57 THEN 'Residential support (EFA funded only)'
WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=58 THEN '19+ Hardship (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'  
WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=59 THEN '20+ Childcare (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)' 
WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=60 THEN 'Residential Access Fund (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'   
WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode IN (61, 62, 63, 64, 65) THEN 'Unassigned'    
ELSE 'N/A'
END AS Bursary, CASE WHEN STUD_Gender='M' THEN 'Male'
WHEN STUD_Gender='F' THEN 'Female'
END AS Gender, 
CASE 
WHEN STUD_Ethnicity= 31 THEN 'White - English / Welsh / Scottish / Northern Irish / British'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 32 THEN 'White - Irish'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 33 THEN 'White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 34 THEN 'White - Any Other White background'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 35 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black Caribbean'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 36 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black African'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 37 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Asian'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 38 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - Any Other Mixed / multiple ethnic background'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 39 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Indian'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 40 THEN 'Asian/ Asian British - Pakistani'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 41 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Bangladeshi'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 42 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Chinese'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 43 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Any other Asian background'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 44 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - African'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 45 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Caribbean'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 46 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Any other Black / African / Caribbean background'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 47 THEN 'Other ethnic group - Arab'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 98 THEN 'Any Other'
WHEN  STUD_Ethnicity= 99 THEN 'Not provided'
END AS Ethnicity,
CASE 
WHEN g.GNUC_Flag_1 = 1 THEN 'Yes'
WHEN g.GNUC_Flag_1 = 0 THEN 'No'
END AS [Looked After Child],
CASE 
WHEN SUB1.GNUC_Type = 'STYR' THEN 'Yes'
WHEN SUB1.GNUC_Type != 'STYR' THEN 'No'
END AS ALS
INTO WarehouseAttendance_New                    
FROM        
sql10.ng.dbo.REGTrgstudt 
INNER JOIN
sql10.ng.dbo.REGSrgsessn ON REGT_REGH_ISN = REGS_REGH_ISN  
inner join sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender
ON REGS_Session_Date=VDC_day_date      
INNER JOIN TTWeeks on REGT_year=TTWeeks.REMSYear
and VDC_week_no=WholeYearWeekNo and VDC_cal_year=REMSYear
INNER JOIN
sql10.ng.dbo.REGHrghdr ON REGH_ISN = REGT_REGH_ISN 
INNER JOIN
sql10.ng.dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader ON REGT_Provision_Code = PRPH_Code 
INNER JOIN
sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes AS ML2 ON ML2.GNCD_General_Code = PRPH_ML2 AND ML2.GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2' 
INNER JOIN
sql10.ng.dbo.STEN ON STEN_Student_ID = REGTrgstudt.REGT_Student_ID AND STEN_Provision_Code = REGTrgstudt.REGT_Provision_Code AND
STEN_Provision_Instance = REGT_Provision_Instance 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  sql10.ng.dbo.STFMLearnerFAM ON STFM_Year = STEN_Year AND STFM_Student_ID = STEN_Student_ID 
INNER JOIN
sql10.ng.dbo.STYRstudentYR ON STYR_Student_ID = REGT_Student_ID AND STYR_Year = REGT_Year   
INNER JOIN (SELECT GNUC_Type, GNUC_Year, GNUC_Entity_ISN FROM sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom 
WHERE (GNUC_Year IN ('2013', '2014', '2015'))) AS SUB1 ON REGT_Year = SUB1.GNUC_Year 
AND STYR_ISN = SUB1.GNUC_Entity_ISN
INNER JOIN
(SELECT     ACYR_College_Year
FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.ACYR
WHERE      (ACYR_College_Year in (2015, 2014, 2013, 2012))) AS SUB ON REGT_Year = SUB.ACYR_College_Year
INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.STUDStudent on STYR_Student_ID=STUD_Student_ID
JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom g ON STUD_ISN = g.GNUC_Entity_ISN AND g.GNUC_Type = 'STUD'       
INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.REGDropin ON REGT_REGH_ISN = REGD_REGH_ISN AND REGT_Student_ID = REGD_Student_ID 
AND 
REGD_Session_No = REGS_Session_No
INNER JOIN
sql10.ng.dbo.RGATAttendance ON REGD_Attendance_Mark = RGAT_Attendance_Code 
INNER JOIN
sql10.ng.dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance AS pit ON pit.PRPI_Code = REGT_Provision_Code 
and pit.prpi_instance = REGT_Provision_Instance
INNER JOIN
(SELECT     GNCD_General_Code, GNCD_Description
FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes
WHERE      (GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2')) AS q ON q.GNCD_General_Code =  RTrim(PRPH_ML2) 
END
GO
```

I want to make sure I am using correct SQL in SQL Server Agent -> Steps

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_WarehouseAttendance_New]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

I would like to know if above query deletes existing data in the table or just appends to existing data which should not be the case.

Also, whenever I execute this procedure either using sql job or in query, it throws Lock timeout request error as below.

[image: Lock Timeout error]

Kindly let me know how this can be resolved.

Thanks,
Ar

Execution Plan below(Source Server - SQL10.NG):

[image: Plan1]

[image: Plan2]

[image: Plan3]

[image: Plan 4]

[image: Plan 5]

Client Statistics:

[image: Client Stats]

Comment: What you show is not a query.  The answer depends on what the procedure sp_WharehouseAttendance_New does.

Comment: Mark - please see above.

Comment: It is a poor rpactice to name stored procs with sp. That is reserved for system procs. Every time you execute, the database will first look to see if it has a system proc named that and only goes to the user proc if it doesn't find out. That is a performance hit on every single call of the proc and if they ever name a system proc with the same name, then the user proc cannot ever be called.

Comment: Thanks HLGEM for your suggestion I will rename it without 'sp'

Answer (score 2):

The statement that you posted is valid, but is better that you test before to apply, remember that the job will be a simple EXECUTOR of this sentence, I don't understand the question:

"I would like to know if above query deletes existing data in the table"

This action need to be performs in your SP, if you need to clean all the data before to execute it you can use a

```
TRUNCATE TABLE YourTable
```

Comment: I am using DROP TABLE in my stored proc. Please see above

Answer (score 1):

in the start of your stored procedure, your script will drop the table if it exists already:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New;
```

The SELECT later will redirect the data to a new table with the same name:

```
....
INTO WarehouseAttendance_New                    
...
```

The answer to your answer is: The script drops the table(if exists), and then create again with the new data. If the drop table fails, the script will fail instead of appending the data

Answer (score 1):

The answer of t-clausen.dk is correct, I would like to recommend you that try to add a TRANSACTION in your Sp, the best article about this topic I have read is this:

http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

The other aspects is the real necessity of drop and recreate always the table, why not only truncate table?

Comment: Thanks for the link Geovanny. I will update my query

Comment: Whenever I try to execute the stored proc I am getting Lock timeout request error...Any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: Try to post the Execution Plan for trying to help you

Comment: Please see above screenshots

Comment: Geovanny - any idea if COMMIT before END of stored proc will help?

Comment: No, the use of transacción is to keep the integrity of your data, because apply all the change like a unit keeping ACID properties,  I recomend you that find árticles abouy the subject un especial from Kalen Delaney.

The execution plan that you showed not say anything, could you extract the  part of Select..Into and show the execution plan.

Comment: Aruna, your query is executing against a Linked Server? Because according the Execution Plan that you show probably the delay and the time that the SP take is for the processing through linked Server and the best option is to review the query in the Source Server.  I guess that the table: sql10.ng.dbo.RGATAttendance is in the Remote Server.

Comment: Geovanny - Please check above

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that if you are going to use drop table and then select into, you need to specify the schema in the select into. Other wise if someone without dbo rights (which should be virtually everyone who touches the database) executes the proc, it will create a new table in the wrong schema and then whatever queries your table will not find the table. So the

```
Into WarehouseAttendance_New
```

line should be:

```
Into dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New
```

Personally I am not found of drop table and select into for anything except a temp table. As it is, you create no indexes on the new table either which is certainly a problem for later querying. I would prefer that you Truncate and then insert into. And depending on the number of records, it might be better to update any records that have changed and insert new ones rather than drop a table with a million records and then reinsert a million records when really only 15-20 of them were affected.

As far as your performance issue, I am not at all surprised that this particular query takes a lot of time. In the first place, likely many records are returned, in the second place you have a lot of syntax structures that would not be performant including case statements, lots of joins and even a few likes with a wildcard as the first character. Depending on how busy the database tables you are getting this information from are, you might also have a lot of blocking.

This is not the kind of thing we would necessarily be able to help you with on the Internet. This type of performance tuning and design is a job for database experts working over the course of several hours or days to find and resolve the issues.

Comment: HLGEM - you are right I did run into locking issues :(

Answer (score 1):

I can see in the Execution Plan a lot of problems, at the begining with the high number of Paralellism operator and Hash Match, I believe that is better that you create a new post of asking about the strategy to solve the evident problems related with the query, remember, the problem is not the Jobs, the mainly problem is cost of the query and the fact that this is executed through a Linked Server.

Regards !!!